# "{% extends %}" and "{% include %}" in Django Templates

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, templatetags

I would like to provide the same content inside 2 different base files.

So, I'm trying to do this:

page1.html:

```
{% extends "base1.html" %}
{% include "commondata.html" %}
```

page2.html:

```
{% extends "base2.html" %} 
{% include "commondata.html" %}
```

The problem is that I can't seem to use both extends and include. Is there some way to do that?  And if not, how can I accomplish the above?

`commondata.html` overrides a block that is specified in both `base1.html` and `base2.html`

The purpose of this is to provide the same page in both `pdf` and `html` format, where the formatting is slightly different. The above question though simplifies what I'm trying to do so if I can get an answer to that it will solve my problem.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

When you use the extends template tag, you're saying that the current template extends another -- that it is a child template, dependent on a parent template.  Django will look at your child template and use its content to populate the parent.

Everything that you want to use in a child template should be within blocks, which Django uses to populate the parent.  If you want use an include statement in that child template, you have to put it within a block, for Django to make sense of it.  Otherwise it just doesn't make sense and Django doesn't know what to do with it.

The Django documentation has a few really good examples of using blocks to replace blocks in the parent template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance

Comment: my commondata.html has the block defined in it.  But it is not replacing the parent tempalte's block...  If instead of doing an include I write the exact data twice in both page1.html and page2.html then of course it does work.  But I want to factor out that commonality into commondata.html.

Comment: Seems to work, I remember trying this but I must have had a typo or something at the time causing it not to work.

Comment: see my answer below for why it didn't work for me the first time, I'll leave you with the accepted answer though because you answered the question I asked correctly.

Answer (score 86):

From Django docs:

> The include tag should be considered as an implementation of "render this subtemplate and include the HTML", not as "parse this subtemplate and include its contents as if it were part of the parent". This means that there is no shared state between included templates -- each include is a completely independent rendering process.

So Django doesn't grab any blocks from your commondata.html and it doesn't know what to do with rendered html outside blocks.

Answer (score 45):

This should do the trick for you: put include tag inside of a block section.

page1.html:

```
{% extends "base1.html" %}

{% block foo %}
   {% include "commondata.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

page2.html:

```
{% extends "base2.html" %}

{% block bar %}
   {% include "commondata.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What significance does 'foo' or 'bar' blocks have here? Do you reference them in the base templates? I'm scratching my head as to why this would work.

Answer (score 13):

More info about why it wasn't working for me in case it helps future people:

The reason why it wasn't working is that {% include %} in django doesn't like special characters like fancy apostrophe.  The template data I was trying to include was pasted from word.  I had to manually remove all of these special characters and then it included successfully.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pull in blocks from an included file into a child template to override the parent template's blocks.  However, you can specify a parent in a variable and have the base template specified in the context.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#extends):

> {% extends variable %} uses the value of variable. If the variable evaluates to a string, Django will use that string as the name of the parent template. If the variable evaluates to a Template object, Django will use that object as the parent template.

Instead of separate "page1.html" and "page2.html", put `{% extends base_template %}` at the top of "commondata.html".  And then in your view, define `base_template` to be either "base1.html" or "base2.html".

Answer (score 2):

Added for reference to future people who find this via google:  You might want to look at the {% overextend %} tag provided by the mezzanine library for cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 10th Dec 2015**: As pointed out in the comments, *ssi* is deprecated since version 1.8. According to the documentation:

> This tag has been deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10. Use the include tag instead.

---

In my opinion, the right (best) answer to this question is the one from **podshumok**, as it explains why the behaviour of include when used along with inheritance.

However, I was somewhat surprised that nobody mentioned the **ssi** tag provided by the Django templating system, which is specifically designed for *inline* including an external piece of *text*. Here, *inline* means the external text will not be interpreted, parsed or interpolated, but simply "copied" inside the calling template.

Please, refer to the documentation for further details (be sure to check your appropriate version of Django in the selector at the lower right part of the page).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ssi

From the documentation:

> ```
> ssi
> Outputs the contents of a given file into the page.
> Like a simple include tag, {% ssi %} includes the contents of another file
> – which must be specified using an absolute path – in the current page
> ```

Beware also of the security implications of this technique and also of the required ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS define, which must be added to your settings files.

Comment: Note, as of 1.8, ssi has been deprecated in favor of Include. [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-include)

Answer (score 1):

You can use both [{% extends %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#extends) and [{% include %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include) in one template.

For example, there is `base.html` below which displays `Base`:

```
# "templates/base.html"

<p>Base</p>

{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

And, there is `additional.html` below which displays `Additional`:

```
# "templates/additional.html"

<p>Additional</p>
```

And, there is `index.html` below which displays `Index`:

```
# "templates/index.html"

<p>Index</p>
```

Now, you can extend `base.html` and include `additional.html` inside of [{% block %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatetag-block) in addition to `<p>Index</p>` in `index.html` as shown below, then render `index.html` with a Django View:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Index</p>
    {% include "additional.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Then, `Base`, `Index` and `Additional` are displayed as shown below:

```
Base

Index

Additional
```

Be careful, the code outside of [{% block %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatetag-block) below and the code inside of `{% block %}` which `base.html` doesn't have below are ignored in `index.html`:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% extends "base.html" %}

<p>Index</p>
{% include "additional.html" %}

{% block test %}
    <p>Index</p>
    {% include "additional.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

So, only `Base` is displayed as shown below:

```
Base
```