# Django: Is it possible to call a template from inside another template?

Tags: python, django, templates

Not sure if what I'm asking for is impossible or if I'm misunderstanding the way Django templates work.

Let's say I have a template named `base.html`. This contains things that should be included in all templates: meta tags, css, titles, etc.

I then have a route named `main` that calls `main.html` which extends `base.html`. All good so far.

Inside of `main.html` I have a `{% for %}` loop. For organizational reasons I'd like each of the items being iterated through to be rendered with their own separate template which would be saved in a different file, and that presumably would inherit all of `main.html`'s context attributes. Hence, calling a template from another template.

I want to do this because the template that would render each iterated item (let's call it `cards.html`) will get pretty large and it would simply be easier to break it off into its own file.

Is this possible to do? From what I've been able to tell Django's templates inherit going backwards, that is, you call the child template which extends the parent which might extend another parent. In this case, `cards.html` will never render because no one can ever call it.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the [include tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#include).

Comment: See also this discussion of mixing `extends` and `include`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408925/django-templates-include-and-extends

Comment: Thanks, @PeterDeGlopper. Issue resolved. The problem was I was trying to extend the parent from inside the child, not realizing the child should be nothing but blocks.