# Django extends only one template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-2.1

I have an app called `exercise_tracker` and want to extend my `base.html` with two templates: `exercise_list.html` and `footer.html`. For `exercise_list.html`I have set a `view` for `footer.html` not. 
It doesn't render the content of `footer.html`. Can you give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Exercise

def exercise_list(request):
    exercises = Exercise.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'exercise_tracker/exercise_list.html', {"exercises": exercises})
```

base.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block footer %}
            <p>Footer placeholder</p>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

exercise_list.html

```
{% extends 'exercise_tracker/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <table>
    {% for exercise in exercises %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ exercise.date_learned }}</td>
            <td>{{ exercise.time_studied }}</td>
            <td>{{ exercise.language_learned }}</td>
            <td>{{ exercise.description|linebreaksbr }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

footer.html

```
{% extends 'exercise_tracker/base.html' %}

{% block footer %}
    <p>Footer</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I don't think two extends work together. You can use extend for your main content and add header and/or footer with include tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using the `extends` template tag tells Django to populate the blocks in the parent template with the block content defined in the used child template only!**

When you populate only the `content` block in your *exercice_list.html* then only the `content` block of the *base.html* will be populated when you call your `exercice_list` view. This is because django does not look for what other templates might extend the parent template, so it doesn't care that there is a *footer.html* somewhere that also extends it. If you want the content from *footer.html* inclded when you call  the `exercice_list` view then you need to add it either already in the *base.html* or then in the *exercice_list.html*.

It is totally fine to keep the footer in a separate template, but you need to add it, also as a block, to the *exercice_list.html*:

```
{% extends 'exercise_tracker/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<table>
{% for exercise in exercises %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ exercise.date_learned }}</td>
        <td>{{ exercise.time_studied }}</td>
        <td>{{ exercise.language_learned }}</td>
        <td>{{ exercise.description|linebreaksbr }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
    {% include "footer.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

And your *footer.html* might look like:

```
<p>Footer</p>
```

If you want to do some more reading about this, an SO question about `include` and `extend` is a good starting point: [django templates: include and extends](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1408925/1622937)
Or then the excellent django docs about [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance).

*Hope that helped and happy coding!*

Comment: Thank you for explaining the context to my problem. I understand now why it didn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you edit your **exercise_list.html**

```
{% extends 'exercise_tracker/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <table>
    {% for exercise in exercises %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ exercise.date_learned }}</td>
            <td>{{ exercise.time_studied }}</td>
            <td>{{ exercise.language_learned }}</td>
            <td>{{ exercise.description|linebreaksbr }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}
   <p>Footer placeholder</p>
{% endblock %}
```

In **base.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block footer %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

It may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a separate template for footer. If you are using same footer for the entire website you can just code it in base.html . If you want to override it only someplaces just add a block for footer in the base template and ovverride it where you want to.

This should give you an idea :

**Base.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    // Site-Wide Links , CDN go here
    {% block head %} 
    {% endblock %
  </head>
  <body>
// Base code goes here
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}    
<footer>
// Base Footer goes here
    {% block footer %}
    {% endblock %}

</footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Some_template.html :**

```
{% extends 'exercise_tracker/base.html' %} 
    {% block head %}
    //Your CSS , CDN here 
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
 // Your HTML here
    {% endblock %}

    {% block footer %}
//Your Footer Here if you need to add something
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use `{% include 'something/footer.html' %}` in your templates